# How do games host a game with people connected without port forwarding?

Tags: host, portforwarding, upnp

So I see games such as Call of Duty and Halo have the clients (the users) as hosts and people from around the world connect to their console through their modem/router.

I understand how the clients would connect to the host:

> A main server holds all the users and create a 'lobby'. Once a host is
>   chosen, the main server broadcasts the IP of the host to the clients
>   and all simultaneously connect to the host once the host tells the
>   main server that it is ready to accept users.

How is this possible as the console isn't usually port-forwarded to the outer world. Does the game create a temporary port forward to the console?

(I have recently learnt about [Internet Gateway Device Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol) and knows about [Universal Plug and Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upnp) for a while. Which one of these should game developers be/start using to allow clients to host their own servers without any main server tunneling of the data?)

Comment: Basically it's called relaying.  All hosts link up to an external server.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question - Yes UPnP is the way most applications typically open ports through a NAT router to allow the hosting of a server. You can see my [answer to another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24504558/420787) on how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood was:

How can clients connect to (for example) another Xbox if that guy's house isn't port forwarded?

My understanding is that he isn't hosting the server. He's just administrating a mini server created on the main one. The main one is port forwarded, as the clients don't need to be (outgoing connections are usually allowed in most computers/routers. Its the incoming ones that need to be watched)

He is a client as well, and all of you are connecting to the main server off in China or wherever.

This is why when servers go down, consoles lose all multiplayer. Meanwhile, computers, which allow (usually) personal server creation, can continue. These player servers must be port forwarded, as I'm sure you know if you ever tried to host minecraft (or any game really) without hamachi